# Autonumbering in forms in Access

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form in access that saves the data in a database and I want one of the fields to be automatically calculated as the next value in line as the ID so that the user doesnt write the ID. does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: See this article: http://superuser.com/questions/288087/how-do-i-set-the-first-value-of-autonumber-in-access

Answer (score 2):

Create your table using an Autonumber data type.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually create your tables then this statement

```
CREATE TABLE TableThatIncrements
(
    Id AUTOINCREMENT(1001,1)
)
```

Alternately you can edit your existing table Id column using:

```
ALTER TABLE TableThatIncrements
   ALTER COLUMN Id AUTOINCREMENT(1001,1)
```

If you do not, then you can change per the article I mentioned via the GUI interface.  See steps in this article:  https://superuser.com/questions/288087/how-do-i-set-the-first-value-of-autonumber-in-access

You can run a query in Access by doing the following:

```
Go to the "Create" tab and click "Query Design"

Just close the window that appears which asks you to select tables, we don't need that.

Go to the "Design" tab and click the button with the arrow until you get a textual input screen.  (By default, it says SELECT;).

Delete the default text and paste the above query.

Click "Run".
```